# How can I set the minimum term frequency when creating a lucene index?

Tags: java, lucene

At first I have to say that I am completely new to Lucene and therefore my question may be a little bit stupid.

What I would like to do is to create an index which contains terms that occurs at least a specific number of times in a document. The reason why I would like to do that is that I tried to search for a term which only occurs two times and I got zero results. I tried to find where I can tweak this parameter but without success. I had a look at the index using [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/) and it seems that the term does not occur in the index file.

The version of Lucene I must use is 2.0 because I have to use another library which only works with index files of version 2.0.

I would appreciate any hint regarding this problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is it possible that you looking for term that belongs to noise dictionary?

Comment: That is definitely possible, yes! Is there a way to change the behavior of Lucene regarding noise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your answer on my comment you can manage stop-word dictionary by creating analyzer

[StandardAnalyzer(File stopwords)](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html#StandardAnalyzer%28java.io.File%29)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I fear that the problem is not related to stopwords. I think that the problem is that the term I would like to search for occurs only 2 times in the document and I think that because of that Lucene does not add it to the index. My index consists of only about 350 words and this includes words like "and", "or", ....

Comment: @zlajo what is the way you check word in the index. Unique words (2 in your case) are extracted well by lucene. So it is not a problem. Another issue that lucene can filter words less than 3 letters. In any way - try to add +10 same words in your 350 set to check this issue.

Comment: Does lucene in general exclude any words from being index (except for words shorter than 3 letters)? Maybe there is a way to configure those rules which decide whether a word should be added to the index or not. Thanks!

Comment: @zlajo sure, this part of Lucene is done by tokenizer. So select appropriate implementation (e.g. LetterTokenizer) or configure StandartTokenizer as you want